# Blender is currently unusable on NVIDIA GPUs (M - MX family)

Tags: discussion, status-completed

### Update 2

Waited a couple versions or so, can confirm issue is now gone in **376.33**. Tested on a Dell XPS 15 with a 960M.

---

### Update

#### This issue seems to be only on the M - MX family. Desktop GPUs aren't affected.

---

Due to the influx of the "Blender is lagging" posts, I'm going to pin this on the main site until the issue is resolved, and our close-votes review queue calms down. From what I've seen only 2.78 users are posting but it might affect other versions as well.

See [Blender 2.78 with Windows 10 lags when interacting with the UI](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68311/blender-2-78-with-windows-10-lags-when-interacting-with-the-ui) and the official release thread for the driver is here https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/978895/geforce-drivers/official-376-09-game-ready-whql-display-driver-feedback-thread-released-11-28-16-/1/

### DO NOT UPDATE TO Official 376.09 Game Ready WHQL Display Driver (Released 11/28/16).

If you have already, the best "fix" is to rollback to your previous working driver, personally **375.95** seems to be a good version in the same month. If for some reason you can't do this, open the NVIDIA control panel and force Blender to use the intel chipset, if you have that option (not recommended as you might see flickering).

Comment: What's the correct response to all the lag questions? Close as off-topic because it's a driver issue or answer one and merge all the duplicates into that?

Comment: @RayMairlot We support hardware type questions to an extent now remember, the latter is what was done and is recommended. Also there is a new driver out that I should test and see if the issue was resolved.

Comment: We support hardware questions? Have you got a link to a meta question regarding this?

Comment: @RayMairlot Woops, I meant to say performance, kinda interleaves but yeah as detailed here http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/354/canonical-posts-for-hardware-questions one post for any widespread issue as a canonical post or answer and link to that.

Comment: Just leaving this as reference link to the original question in case one needs to close as duplicate http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68311/blender-2-78-with-windows-10-lags-when-interacting-with-the-ui

Comment: To clarify, by M - MX family you mean the *mobile* GPUs, not workstation-class Maxwell architecture GPUs which are also prefixed with an m.

Comment: @PGmath yes, mobile

Comment: I am using NVIDIA's graphics driver v376.54, and the problem was still there for me. I removed the driver and Blender is running smooth. The problem is still here guys.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan Maybe update to latest? 378 here working fine.

Comment: @iKlsR, works like a charm. :-)

Comment: the problem is still occuring in 397.93 version, using 2.78b I hope they will deal with this in 2.80, i'm using gt755m

Comment: What is this post doing on meta?

Comment: @NicolaSap There was a bug in a Nvidia driver and we were getting flooded with questions related to it. It served as a place to point users to since it could be seen in the sidebar on the main site.